# Why does the HTML specification forbids the usage of "true" and "false" as values in boolean attributes?

Tags: html

I have a question to the sense of the html specification at: 
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes

This is clear:

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.

But why I am not allowed to use "true" or "false" as values?

> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

Since the presence of the attribute is enough to have a "true" value I could use ANY value like "blablabla". But why not "true" and "false"? Just to avoid confusion?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an opinion. StackOverflow is for looking for help figuring out coding issues, so this question may not be appropriate for this forum.

Comment: The specification should be precise and unambiguous. You are right, there were many ways how to specify it. Why did they choose this way? Probably because it was shorter. Does it really matter?

Answer (score 1):

> Since the presence of the attribute is enough to have a "true" value I could use ANY value like "blablabla".

No. That's invalid. You can specify either the attribute name alone, or the name and the defined value (which is the same as the name).

> But why not "true" and "false"?

It's a holdover from SGML.

When boolean attributes were originally implemented they used a feature which allowed you to specify **only the value**.

This meant less typing and smaller, more readable files.

Obviously `<input type="checkbox" checked>` is much easier to understand than `<input type="checkbox" true>`, so the value and the name is the same.

HTML 5 doesn't define itself in SGML terms, so it says that you can specify the attribute name alone rather than the value (even though they are the same) but it needs to be backwards compatible with existing HTML parsers.